# VLC not displaying video properly in FullScreen?

Tags: vlc

I have VLC 3.0.0 installed on my Ubuntu 15.10 PC. VLC does not display video properly in full screen.

Windowed mode:
[image]

Full Screen: 
[image]

I have tried reinstalling VLC, removing VLC completely using purge & then installing, removing VLC using Synaptic & then installing, but this issue remains. Any solution? Note: I used to be able to use VLC fine some time ago, this issue just came randomly..

Comment: Right click on the fullscreen mode>Video>Always adapted to the window. Is it checked? Please note that the last VLC version stabily supported by Ubuntu is 2.2.1.3 (last one in official repos). If you installed your 3.0.0 from an external repository, you *have to* report the bug there.

Comment: Actually, the option is Always Fit to Window(in my installation, anyway) and yes, its checked. I have installed VLC from `ppa:videolan/stable-daily`. I used to have VLC 2.2.1 and faced the same problem, so I removed it and installed 3.0.0..I don't think this is a bug in 3.0.0 as I had the same issue with previous versions...

Comment: There is a problem with qt5 at the moment, have a look here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/vlc-2-2-2-a-4175571633/

Comment: How do I apply the patch? Sorry if this is obvious, I am a newb..

Answer (score 49):

In *Tools > Preferences > Video > Output* change to *"OpenGL GLX video output(XCB)"*, save and restart vlc:

[image]

If you use Intel GPU, following setting speeds up decoding.
In *Tools > Preferences > Input/Codecs > Hardware-accelerated decoding* chant to *"VA-API video decoder via X11"*:

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have some references. But that worked like a charm!

Comment: With Ubuntu as Vmware client it worked when selecting "XVideo output (XCB)" as Video > Display > Output (first screen of the answer above).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as soon as i disabled my video card. Tried many things but none worked. The first thing i noticed after disabling my video card is my screen resolution changed. So i changed it from 800*600 to 1024*768 and played a video. To my amusement it was better than before. So i set it to 1280*1024 and its perfect now. I did it just now like 10 minutes back and immediately posting this so that this one might work for some people.

Answer (score 0):

The function that I had to disable on my Mac is *Black screen in fullscreen mode*.
Found in

```
Preferences --> Video --> Black screen in fullscreen mode (untick)
```

Hope it helps.