# Mouse cursor disappear on video playback on ubuntu 16.10 on vlc

Tags: vlc, 16.10

Mouse cursor disappear on video playback on ubuntu 16.10 on vlc.

As I hover my mouse pointer over the video playback, the mouse pointer disappears eventhough when i move around the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 15):

I had a very similar issue to yours, even the menus were being blocked by the video.  Also, when I stretched my screen, the playing video stayed the same size and didn't stretch along.

If this sounds like the same situation you have, I was able to fix via this other SO answer ([VLC not displaying video properly in FullScreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736923/vlc-not-displaying-video-properly-in-fullscreen/775378#775378))

@Huang Dongsung's answer:

In Tools > Preferences > Video > Output change to "OpenGL GLX video output(XCB), save and restart vlc.

If you use Intel GPU, following setting speeds up decoding. In Tools > Preferences > Input/Codecs > Hardware-accelerated decoding chant to "VA-API video decoder via X11"

Comment: The Intel GPU instructions fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: It worked like a charm